# Actionscript help : 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before abc

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, text, actionscript, urlrequest

I was workin on a project, and i need to put a variable, between the text in URLRequest

```
url4 = new URLRequest("text/"abc"/text.png");
```

Any help??
Btw let's say abc is the variable i want to put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `+` to add strings and variables together in AS3.

```
url4 = new URLRequest("text/"+abc+"/text.png");
```